# Linq to Dictionary with key and a list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

My data is as under in two tables

```
Master Columns 
ID    MyDateTime 
1     07 Sept
2     08 Sept
```

MyDatetime column in above has unique index

```
Detail Columns
ID     Data1     Data2    Data3
1      a         b        c 
1      x         y        z
1      f         g        h
2      a         b        c
```

I want to populate this in a dictionary. I have tried

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Detail>> result = (
                          from master in db.master
                          from details in db.detail
                          where (master.ID == detail.ID)
                          select new
                          {
                              master.MyDateTime,
                              details
                          }).Distinct().ToDictionary(key => key.MyDateTime, value => new List<Detail> { value.details });
```

I expect two rows in the dictionary

```
1, List of 3 rows as details
2, List of 1 row as details
```

I get an error where it complains about the key of the dictionary entered twice. The key would be the datetime which is unique in the master

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is precisely what lookups are for - so use `ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionary`:

```
ILookup<DateTime, Detail> result =
    (from master in db.master
     join details in db.detail on master.ID equals detail.ID
     select new { master.MyDateTime, details })
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.MyDateTime, pair => pair.details);
```

(You shouldn't need to use `Distinct`, and note the use of a join instead of a second `from` and a `where` clause.)

Comment: Where to use dictionary and where LookUp jon?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Use a dictionary for a "key to single value" mapping, and a lookup for "key to multiple value" mapping (when you're query; Lookup is immutable, so you can't use it when you're mutating the collection).